# Is there any way to retrieve data of a mysql database that has been uninstalled

Tags: mysql, uninstall

I wanted to know if there is a way to recover the data of a de-installed mysql server.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by uninstalled/deinstalled??

Comment: I mean removing mysql from windows add/remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mysql databases are *usually* stored as files in the filesystem in some location different from the mysqld binaries (e.g. /var/lib/mysql) and not deleted during package removal. You can access the data just by configuring a mysql instance's "datadir" to look there and launching it.

/etc/my.cnf:

```
[...]
[mysqld]
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
[...]
```

Just search your filesystem for files named `"ibdata1"`, `"*.MYD"` (myISAM table data) or `"*.MYI"` (myISAM table indexes) to get a clue where your files might be if your old my.cnf is not accessible for a reference anymore.

Comment: Not a *nix system...

Comment: I've just seen you are using Windows. In this case the datadir is per default in %programfiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server <version>\Data. Is this directory still present on your system?

Comment: the problem is I cannot find this directory, can't it be somewhere else?

Comment: @Navid, it can be just about anywhere (on the computer, network, SAN, remote sites connected via VPN... heck, you might be using cloud storage for all we know); if it isn't in that folder.

Comment: Just run a search for *.MYD across your disks. If you don't find anything, the data is probably gone. You might want to check out some data recovery / undelete tools if you don't have a backup and **really really** need that data and a partial recovery would do for you - the chances of getting it back in one piece and complete are usually rather bad.

Answer (score 1):

It should still be in the installation location, under the data folder (ex, `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.0\Data`)

Answer (score 1):

When MYSQL is uninstalled all the folders are removed except data folder present at.

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data

At this location a folder having name same as the schema/database on which you were working earlier will be present.Copy this **folder** and **ibdata1** file at a separate location.

Now reinstall MYSQL again and copy the **earlier saved contents**(**folder** and **ibdata1**) at this location

Open Mysql Administrator and perform the backup of database.